# Actionscript 3.0 Perfect Collision Detection registration point center?

Tags: actionscript-3, collision-detection

hey i have a problem with Collision Detection i used this example from a website http://www.freeactionscript.com/2009/05/pixel-perfect-collision-detection/ but it only works when your Object's registration point is on the upper left corner what should i change in the code if let's say the registration point is on the center?

here is the code:

```
package
{
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

public class CollisionTest 
{
// vars
private var _returnValue:Boolean;

private var _onePoint:Point;
private var _twoPoint:Point;

private var _oneRectangle:Rectangle;
private var _twoRectangle:Rectangle;

private var _oneClipBmpData:BitmapData;
private var _twoClipBmpData:BitmapData;

private var _oneOffset:Matrix;
private var _twoOffset:Matrix;

/**
 * Simple collision test. Use this for objects that are not rotated.
 * @param   clip1   Takes DisplayObjectContainer as argument. Can be a Sprite, MovieClip, etc.
 * @param   clip2   Takes DisplayObjectContainer as argument. Can be a Sprite, MovieClip, etc.
 * @return  Collision True/False
 */
public function simple(clip1:DisplayObjectContainer, clip2:DisplayObjectContainer):Boolean
{
    _returnValue = false;

    _oneRectangle = clip1.getBounds(clip1);
    _oneClipBmpData = new BitmapData(_oneRectangle.width, _oneRectangle.height, true, 0);
    _oneClipBmpData.draw(clip1);

    _twoRectangle = clip2.getBounds(clip2);
    _twoClipBmpData = new BitmapData(_twoRectangle.width, _twoRectangle.height, true, 0);
    _twoClipBmpData.draw(clip2);

    _onePoint = new Point(clip1.x, clip1.y)
    _twoPoint =  new Point(clip2.x, clip2.y)

    if (_oneClipBmpData.hitTest(_onePoint, 255, _twoClipBmpData, _twoPoint, 255))
    {
        _returnValue = true;
    }

    return _returnValue;
}

/**
 * Complex collision test. Use this for objects that are rotated, scaled, skewed, etc
 * @param   clip1   Takes DisplayObjectContainer as argument. Can be a Sprite, MovieClip, etc.
 * @param   clip2   Takes DisplayObjectContainer as argument. Can be a Sprite, MovieClip, etc.
 * @return  Collision True/False
 */
public function complex(clip1:DisplayObjectContainer, clip2:DisplayObjectContainer):Boolean
{
    _returnValue = false;

    _twoRectangle = clip1.getBounds(clip1);
    _oneOffset = clip1.transform.matrix;
    _oneOffset.tx = clip1.x - clip2.x;
    _oneOffset.ty = clip1.y - clip2.y;  

    _twoClipBmpData = new BitmapData(_twoRectangle.width, _twoRectangle.height, true, 0);
    _twoClipBmpData.draw(clip1, _oneOffset);        

    _oneRectangle = clip2.getBounds(clip2);
    _oneClipBmpData = new BitmapData(_oneRectangle.width, _oneRectangle.height, true, 0);

    _twoOffset = clip2.transform.matrix;
    _twoOffset.tx = clip2.x - clip2.x;
    _twoOffset.ty = clip2.y - clip2.y;  

    _oneClipBmpData.draw(clip2, _twoOffset);

    _onePoint = new Point(_oneRectangle.x, _oneRectangle.y);
    _twoPoint = new Point(_twoRectangle.x, _twoRectangle.y);

    if(_oneClipBmpData.hitTest(_onePoint, 255, _twoClipBmpData, _twoPoint, 255))
    {
        _returnValue = true;
    }

    _twoClipBmpData.dispose();
    _oneClipBmpData.dispose();

    return _returnValue;
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well lets put it like this:  How far away is the top left corner from the center point?

```
x += width  * .5;
y += height * .5;
```

Right?

So if the code you posted above only treats it with top left (for whatever reason I don't know why) why not force it to treat it with center point instead?

Perhaps something like this?

```
_onePoint = new Point(clip1.x + _clip.width * .5, clip1.y + _clip.height * .5);
_twoPoint =  new Point(clip2.x + _clip2.width * .5, clip2.y + _clip2.height * .5);
```